# how can I parse prefixed length message from TCP stream in twisted python?

Tags: python, parsing, tcp, twisted, codec

I'm coding to tcp client/server using python twisted 
in order to replace for Java or C#.
I have to parse length prefixed string messages based on ANS(alpha numeric string) in connected permanent session.

- like this :

  - message format : [alpha numeric string:4byte][message data]
  - example-1 : 0004ABCD  ==> ABCD
  - example-2 : 0002AB0005HELLO  ==> AB, HELLO

it can't be solved by IntNProtocol, NetStringProtocol.

And if a client send a 2kb message from application layer, the kernel split message data by MSS(maximum segment size) and send packets are splitted.

in TCP send/receive environment, it often raise like this :

- example : 1000HELLO {not yet arrived 995 byte data}

so it has to wait for receiving spare data using array, queue...

in the twisted, I don't know how to parse multiple large-message.

Anybody help me to give some information or URL?

```
class ClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        # how can I code to parse multiple large message?
        # is there solution to read specific size for data ?
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can implement this protocol using `StatefulProtocol` as a base.  Your protocol basically has two states.  In the first state, you're waiting for 4 bytes which you will interpret as a zero-padded base 10 integer.  In the second state, you're waiting for a number of bytes equal to the integer read in the first state.

```
from twisted.protocols.stateful import StatefulProtocol

class ANSProtocol(StatefulProtocol):
    def getInitialState(self):
        return (self._state_length, 4)

    def _state_length(self, length_bytes):
        length = int(length_bytes)
        return self._state_content, length

    def _state_content(self, content):
        self.application_logic(content)
        return self.getInitialState()

    def application_logic(self, content):
        # Application logic operating on `content`
        # ...
```